# how to ask the user enable location service when my flutter app is in background

Tags: flutter, location, location-services

I am using **Firebase notification** and I get the user location on every notification.

How to ask the user to enable location service when i try to get the location and the service is disable.

I have tried to use [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) and [android intent plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) plugins but when my app is in background it doesn't work because it depend on the **activity**

Comment: I haven't tried this while an app is in the background, but maybe try using [pemission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). When your app receives the notification from Firebase, try utilizing this package and see if it pops up the permissions dialog on the device.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this package is for permissions not for enable services on the device

Comment: So in your scenario, you have permissions to the location, but the user has turned it off for the entire device. So you want to ask them to turn it on? You can modify the notification message to ask them to turn on location services, but you won't be able to act on it without the user interacting with your app or the notification you've sent. Are you having a problem detecting the state of location services on the device?

Comment: Yes, I just want to ask the user to turn the location on when the app in the background and the location is turned off.

No, there is no problem with detecting the state of location services.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to request that the user enable location services when a notification comes in from Firebase. Check the status of location services and if the services are off, then the notification content will be the request for location services. Here is an example of how that might be done.

```
_globalFirebase.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        configureNotification(message: message);
        return Future.value(true);
    },
    onBackgroundMessage:
            Platform.isAndroid ? _myBackgroundMessageHandler : null,
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        configureNotification(message: message);
        return Future.value(true);
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        configureNotification(message: message);
        return Future.value(true);
    }
);

configureNotification({ Map<String, dynamic> message }) async {
    var location = Location();
    bool locationEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!locationEnabled) {
        showNotification(title: "Enable Location Services", content: "Please enable location services to receive important information");
    } else {
        // run your logic and show the message as it comes in
        showNotification(title: ..., content: ...);
    }
}

showNotification({ String title, String content }) async {
    ...
}
```

Of course, you may need to do some other things here with the incoming notification, decide what you want your messaging to be, maybe add interactions with the notification. IDK that's all based on your business/app strategy. Hopefully this gives you an idea of one option for getting that request to the user.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion to help require the user to enable location when the app is in the foreground I want to enable location in the background.

Comment: @MahmoudHajAli You can't/shouldn't be turning on/off services for a device without the user's explicit say-so. For your app? Ok, but still not possible without user interaction.

Comment: I want user interact, but how to show GPS dialog when my app in the background.

Comment: I have used location package but in the background it doesn't work

Comment: This is why I provided this notification solution. It's really the only way to communicate with the user while your app is in the background. You cannot pop a dialog the way you wish to from your app while it's in the background.